# javascript - Sort objects array by key of object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have array of objects that looks like this:

```
var array = [{
key: {name: "C Some name", id: 123},
value: {value: 1, element:"some element"}
}, {
key: {name: "A Name 2", id: 1234},
value: {value: 4, element:"some element 2"}
}, {
key: {name: "B Other name", id: 1235},
value: {value: 2, element:"some element 3"}
}]
```

I want to sort this array by name(inside key object) and value(inside value object). 
Result of sort by name should return this result:

```
[{
key: {name: "A Name 2", id: 1234},
value: {value: 4, element:"some element 2"}
}, {
key: {name: "B Other name", id: 1235},
value: {value: 2, element:"some element 3"}
}, {
key: {name: "C Some name", id: 123},
value: {value: 1, element:"some element"}
}]
```

And result of sort by value should look like this:

```
[{  key: {name: "C Some name", id: 123},
    value: {value: 1, element:"some element"}
}, {
key: {name: "B Other name", id: 1235},
    value: {value: 2, element:"some element 3"}
}, {
key: {name: "A Name 2", id: 1234},
    value: {value: 4, element:"some element 2"}
}]
```

I tried this for sort by name:

```
array.sort(a,b){
return a.key["name"] - b.key["name"];
}
```

And this for sort by value:

```
array.sort(a,b){
return a.key["value"] - b.key["value"];
}
```

but it doesn't work. How can I sort this array?

Comment: `a.key[name]` means you have some variable called `name` and you want to access a property of `a.key` with that matching name. Have you tried `a.key.name` for getting the correct value?

Comment: I should probably set in my question a.key["name"] what is equal to a.key.name

Answer (score 4):

You should compare the strings with `>`.

```js
var array = [{
    key: {name: "C Some name", id: 123},
    value: {value: 1, element:"some element"}
}, {
    key: {name: "A Name 2", id: 1234},
    value: {value: 4, element:"some element 2"}
}, {
    key: {name: "B Other name", id: 1235},
    value: {value: 2, element:"some element 3"}
}];

var newArray = array.sort(function(first, second) {
    var a = first.key.name;
    var b = second.key.name;
    
    if(a > b) {
        return 1;
    } else if(a < b) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: With due respect to moderators, sometimes moderation is excessive !

Answer (score 1):

One of the way to go is like this.

Basically, using the Arrow function for a *Sorting* callback and then comparing the 2 `string` by using `localeCompare`.
`first.key.name.localeCompare(second.key.name)`

For integer values you can directly compare them by doing a subtraction.
`first.value.value - second.value.value`.

The important thing is to know how the *comparer* function works for 2 values `a` and `b`.

> - Less than 0: Sort `a` to be a lower index than `b`.
> - Zero: `a` and `b` should be considered equal, and no sorting performed.
> - Greater than 0: Sort `b`  to be a lower index than `a`

```js
var array = [{
key: {name: "C Some name", id: 123},
value: {value: 1, element:"some element"}
}, {
key: {name: "A Name 2", id: 1234},
value: {value: 4, element:"some element 2"}
}, {
key: {name: "B Other name", id: 1235},
value: {value: 2, element:"some element 3"}
}] 

var resultSortedByName = array.sort( (first,second) => {return first.key.name.localeCompare(second.key.name)} );
console.log(resultSortedByName);

var resultSortedByValue = array.sort( (first,second) => {return (first.value.value - second.value.value)} );
console.log(resultSortedByValue);
```